# ¿Por qué algunos utilizan «augmentativo»?

Tags: adjetivos

No sé si será mi audición (que no es perfecta), pero me pareció oír en algunos programas la palabra «augmentativo». ¿Qué hace esa **g** ahí?

Comment: Sin dar los ejemplos, esto me parece imposible. Nunca he oído una g en esta palabra. ´¿ Y que frase fue?

Comment: Eran frases como: 

> El au**g**mento del coste de la producción... 

Pero, repito, probablemente sea solo un «fallo de fábrica» en mis oídos. Aún así, tenía que preguntarlo para estar segura - si estoy loca o sorda. :D

Comment: Puede que sea sordera...:)

Comment: Qué opciones más alegres... :D

Comment: Jaja. Nos pasa a toda(o)s.

Comment: Se me figura que podría haber sido alguien que se influyera o en el latín (el verbo aumentar provino de "augmentāre" con g) o en el inglés (en el cual aumentativo se dice "augmentative" a más de "augment", etc.), o en un cruce de ambas, me imagino porque le sonaba más culto con g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La única opción que se me ocurre es que esa **g** esté influenciada por el catalán.

Por ejemplo, "aumentar" es, en catalán, "au**g**mentar; y "aumentativo", "au**g**mentativo". Tal como @nopaltepec dijo, influencia del latín.

Saludos. ^^

Comment: Gracias, podría ser, ya que lo he oído (o me ha parecido oírlo) solo en programas españoles (de España ).

Comment: Entonces, seguramente los presentadores son catalanes jeje.

Comment: Es posible, aunque no tengan el acento muy marcado. 